# can i operate ubuntu OS stricktly through interface? without being forced to operate through command line?

Tags: upgrade

I am no computer nor Ubuntu expert, but I absolutely love it. Please help!

I need to know how to add media players, upgrade adobe flash, and operate software for hardware products.

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you want to accomplish. As it stand, your question is too vague to provide any solutions. Please give us some details. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

NO operating system is 100% GUI.  You have to operate using command line sometimes.

But to put you at ease, Ubuntu has 2 major GUI to enable you to install applications, upgrade software, and remove, among other things.

One is called Synaptic Package Manager, which allows you to do just that.

Installing Synaptic can be done in multiple ways, one of which is terminal,  just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

You can also install it from the Ubuntu Software Center, or by clicking [**Install Synaptic** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic/)

[image]

The other one is, of course the Ubuntu Software center.  Ubuntu software center is already available once you install Ubuntu.

[image]

With both you can search for an application, or choose a category, and you will see all the applications available in that category.